# Error while removing mysql-server

Tags: mysql

I get an error while removing mysql:

[image]

Comment: please don't add a picture of your error message, but add the error message as text.

Comment: Did you try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/994072/631600

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get remove mysql*
```