# Cannot install mysql in Ubuntu 20.04 LTE

Tags: package-management, dpkg, mysql, mariadb

I've been struggling to install mysql server in Ubuntu 20.04. I *did* have mariadb installed previously. No matter which post or guide I follow, I always wind up getting this message when I try to install with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-8.0`:

```
done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 194: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.17) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also get this message every time when I try to run mysql:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've tried following many posts, for example:
[Can't get MYSQL8 to work on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235829/cant-get-mysql8-to-work-on-ubuntu-20-04) /n
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uninstall-or-delete-mariadb-completely-for-re-installation/

I'm at a loss and nearly at the point of re-installing Ubuntu, which is ludicrous just to get mysql up and running. I suspect the issue is some sort of trace left over from mariadb, but I've tried everything I can find to eliminate it, including grep'ing dpkg contents and removing manually. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can Google on this site for that specific error message (i.e., the "No such file or directory" for `configure-symlinks`)?  The first hit I got was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980314/cannot-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu16-0-4).  It is for an old version of Ubuntu, but maybe it might help you.  When I see such a problem, I usually would try creating that file just to see if it gets past that point (i.e., if a post-install wants a file, I just create it to see if it can be happy).  The 3rd answer on this page gives similar advice, but do try the others first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took a look at this post, but when I look in `edit-sources` there's nothing mariadb related. I'll try googling the symlinks issue and see if anything else helps.